# preRenderView and ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I have a preRenderView attached to a component A. There is another component B which has ajax. The ajax would render a hidden component which has some text fields in it. The problem is the ajax is not rendering the inputText field

```
<h:form....>
<ui:composition...>
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.action}">
...........
<ui:composition/>

<ui:composition...>
<h:selectOneRadio....>
<f:ajax render="inputTextId"../>
<h:selectOneRadio/>
<ui:fragment rendered="#{condition}">
<h:inputText id="inputTextId" ...../>
<ui:fragment/>
<ui:composition/>
<h:form/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The re-rendering takes place at the client side with help of JavaScript after receiving the Ajax response. It requires the generated HTML output of the to-be-updated component to be **already** in the client side. In your case, it's however never there in the generated HTML output. You need to swap the `rendered` and `id` attributes.

```
<h:selectOneRadio ...>
    <f:ajax render="inputTextWrapperId" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
<h:panelGroup id="inputTextWrapperId" >
    <h:inputText id="inputTextId" rendered="#{condition}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

This issue is unrelated to the pre render view event. You would have exactly the same problem when you removed it.

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2 - Ajax rendering of content which is by itself conditionally rendered](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxRenderingOfContentWhichIsByItselfConditionallyRendered)

Comment: does the post back of ajax trigger the preRenderView?

Comment: is it okay to have the preRenderView for only one component and not for the whole form?

Comment: I'm not sure how that's related. But yes, the pre render view event will be fired before every render of the view, regardless of the type of the request. If you'd like to skip this for postbacks, you'd need to check `FacesContext#isPostback()`, or wait for the new `<f:viewAction>` tag in JSF2 which has an `onPostback` attribute exactly for this.

Comment: BalusC i don't think preRenderView is fired in certain cases like where you are partially(ajax) submitting a form inside ui:include xhtml. Given that you are depending on preRenderView backing bean to get src of ui:include.